# Symmetric Bipartite Matching of Elements in List

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, matching

Start with a random list of integers, say:

```
list = [2,5,7,1,3]
```

Objective: maximally pair each entry in the list with another entry in the list. Entries of values (m,n) can be matched iff log_base_2((m + n) / gcd(m, n)) is NOT an integer. I.e. (7,3) is a valid matching, and (1,3) is not.

I'm pretty sure one way to do this would be to generate two lists, A and B, equivalent to the initial list:

```
A=B=list=[2,5,7,1,3]
```

And then treat it as a Bipartite Matching problem **with the additional constraint that if A[m] matches B[n], then A[n] must also match B[m]** (again, in addition to the matching constraint above). I would imagine a visualization of the resulting flow network would be horizontally symmetric (i.e. along the source-sink axis, hence the title).

I know how to solve a bipartite matching problem using MaxFlow, but can't figure out how to implement this last, bolded constraint. Any help would be very, uh, helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional constraint (if `A[m]` matches `B[n]` then `A[n]` must also match `B[m]`) radically changes the nature of the problem. In fact, that constraint destroys the bipartiteness of the input graph and actually turns it into a general undirected graph. Hence, what you're looking for is an algorithm for finding a maximum matching in a general graph.

The problem can be solved using [Edmonds Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) which exhibits a different approach from the maximum flow solution for the bipartite case (though it does use the notion of an augmenting path). The algorithm exploits the fact that bipartite matching can be easily solved and is tryig, in a way, to turn the input graph into bipartite by collapsing odd-cycles (a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles and thus the number of odd cycles in the graph measures the extent to which the input graph is far from being bipartite). The details of how exactly the algorithm works are well explained in the link above.

Here's [a Python implementation of the algorithm](https://gist.github.com/rogerhub/8343103). The algorithm is fairly efficient for sparse graphs but not very efficient for dense graphs. The density of your graph depends on how many pairs of entries `m, n` satisfy the condition `(m + n) / gcd(m, n)` being a power of 2. If most pairs satisfy the condition the runtime is going to be about `O(n^4)`. In general the runtime is `O(E•V^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! After some searching around, I found a simpler implementation of the Edmonds/'Blossom' Algorithm which I wound up using: 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/
It utilizes Guido Van Rossum's very intuitive Graph structure:
https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/
I hope this helps future readers!

Comment: @Matt, please share a link to the simpler implementation.

Comment: I thought I did - this should be it:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/

Answer (score 0):

This turns out not to be a bipartite matching problem at all - rather, it's the more general class of "Non-Bipartite Maximum Matching." The [Edmonds/'Blossom' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) provides the solution ([Snakile's answer pointed this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794263/symmetric-bipartite-matching-of-elements-in-list/42795002#42795002)).

After some searching around, I found a simple implementation of the Edmonds/'Blossom' Algorithm which I wound up using: 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/

It utilizes Guido Van Rossum's very intuitive Graph structure:
https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Best of luck to future readers!